# ふざけずに! what is the meaning of this exclamation?

Tags: translation

What is the meaning of this exclamation alone?

> ふざけずに！

I know that ふざける means to kid - to play and that ずに means without, so it could be "without kidding" but it doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: So... --> without playing around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an indirect negative imperative. A stereotypical example:

> A:　いや、やっぱりいりません。
>
> B:　そんな固いこと言わずに。もうちびっとわしが負けたらどうです?
>
> A: Nah, actually I don't need it.
>
> B: Aw, don't be like that. How about I cut the price a little bit more?